# Setting Window Height and Width to Parent Window or Screen Resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, window, screen-resolution

I have a `Window` that pops up and allows a user to enter the details of a Company. When the resolution of the user's screen is 1920x1080 the `Window` size is perfect, the text is readable etc etc..

However, as I set the `Width` and `Height` like so `Height="380" Width="1200"`, if the user is on say a laptop with resolution of 1366x768, the `Window` is far too big for the screen and they actually can't see the text.

Instead of specifically setting the `Width` and `Height` which does not work for me at different resolutions, how can I take advantage of `WPF` to allow the `Window` to change size dependent on say, the resolution of the user's monitor or maybe the parent `Window` which is fullscreen?

Comment: You want the app to be full screen or to have relative width and height?

Comment: @Prajwal not full screen, but relative to width and height of the parent window

Answer (score 1):

You should set the width and height using these:

```
width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * 0.8;
height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.8;
```

The 0.8 at the end makes your window 80% the screen size. You can do better things for example set a maximum amount for width and height and etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue but not able to resolve using this.Is there anything we can do?